# show 2 week in the past ( vue.js)

Tags: javascript, date, vue.js

Hi i have this script ( vue.js ) i can see the next 2 weeks works good i must change that i can see 2 weeks on the past ..
Thanks

```js
methods: {
    // Get all days without sunday:
    dates(index) {
      var week = new Array();
      let current = new Date();
      // Starting Monday not Sunday
      current.setDate((current.getDate() - current.getDay() +1));
      for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        let date = new Date(current);
        week.push(moment(date).format('DD.MM.YY'));
        current.setDate(current.getDate() +1);
      }
      return week[index];
    },
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function dates(index) {
      var week = new Array();
      let current = moment().subtract(1, 'days');
      for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        week.push(current.format('DD.MM.YY'));
        current = current.subtract(1, 'days')
      }
      console.log(week);
      return week[index];
}
console.log(dates(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This seems quite inefficient, it copies *current* for no reason, then copies the copy to create a moment object just to get a formatted date. Why not create a single moment object and increment and format that? The "Start Monday not Sunday" only works if the current day is Tuesday.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back in time, you need to **subtract** from the current date:

```
methods: {
    // Get all days without sunday:
    dates(index) {
      var week = new Array();
      let current = new Date();
      // Starting Monday not Sunday
      current.setDate((current.getDate() - current.getDay() +1));
      for (var i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        let date = new Date(current);
        week.push(moment(date).format('DD.MM.YY'));
        current.setDate(current.getDate() - 1); // <-- this line changed
      }
      return week[index];
    },
```